# Cant get my php form to work

Tags: php

I am completely dumbfounded I can't seem to find a solution. Are you supposed to do something additional to create a simple php form?

The php code:

```
<?php

$name = $_GET['name'];
$age = $_GET['age'];

echo "Hello $name. Congratulations on being $age years old!";

?>
```

The form html:

```
    <form action="get.php" method="get">
        <p>What's your name?</br><input type="text" name="name"></p>
        <p>How old are you?</br><input type="text" name="age"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Skicka"></p>
    </form>
```

Thanks in forehand! Have a good day guys.

Comment: Oh sh*t i forgot! Notice: Undefined index: age in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PHP FORMS/get.php on line 6

Comment: You have a space between $_GET and ['age'] maybe?

Comment: You have a space after `$_GET`

Comment: More relevantly, how are both snippets related? And why does the notice say line 6, but your excerpt has the reference in line 3 ?

Comment: The space should not matter.

Comment: The space does not seem to matter. Still the same.

Comment: Is all this on the same page? If so, when you first load it those `$_GET` variables will not be set. Only after you submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the space doesn't matter at all.

<s>The "undefined index" means that you most probably left the input field empty. In that case, it won't be sent by the browser and PHP will throw a notice, that you're accessing an uninitialised variable.</s>

If both code snippets are on the same page, the "undefined index" will always be thrown on the first page load - because there is no submitted data, and by that no filled $_GET array.

The proper way would be to check if there's submitted data, for example:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['name']) || isset($_GET['age'])) {
    // ...
}
?>
```

Also, it's good practise to check for the existence of each index before trying to get it's value, for example:

```
<?php
// check variables with isset() before accessing them
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : '';
$age  = isset($_GET['age'])  ? $_GET['age']  : '';
?>
```

If you're not familiar with what ?: does (or want to have a special handling if a variable isn't set), the above code does the same as this:

```
<?php
// check variables with isset() before accessing them
if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    $name = $_GET['name'];
} else {
    $name = '';
}
if (isset($_GET['age'])) {
    $age = $_GET['age'];
} else {
    $age = '';
}
?>
```

Finally, as [Daniel Ferrans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081895/cant-get-my-php-form-to-work/37081989#37081989) recommended, I'd always use $_POST for form data. That's actually what it's meant for.

Comment: If the form was submitted, the `name` and `age` indexes _would not_ be undefined. They would be sent by the browser, and they would be present in `$_GET` as empty strings.

Comment: @Don'tPanic You're right. Stupid me. But still, I don't understand the notice then. Also, I don't get why it happens on line 6 and not on line 4. *confused*

Comment: I certainly didn't mean to imply that I thought you were stupid. I think there's just some small but crucial piece of missing information from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I would user post instead of Get. (I would not use get in production, because all the information of the form is in the URL)

However, because it seems you are doing tests, I would to the following.
1) in the root folder where you have both the form and the get.php

I would test the get php script by openning an url:

Ex.  http://localhost/get.php?name=TESTNAME&age=xx

in the php I would have the following code

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
$age = $_GET ['age'];

echo "Hello $name. Congratulations on being $age years old!";
?>
```

this should output something. let me know if it works

Answer (score -1):

For test only all in 1 file like this:
test.php

```
<?php

$name = $_GET['name'];
$age = $_GET ['age'];

echo "Hello $name. Congratulations on being $age years old!";

?>
    <form action="test.php" method="get">
        <p>What's your name?</br><input type="text" name="name"></p>
        <p>How old are you?</br><input type="text" name="age"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Skicka"></p>
    </form>
```

its working for me.

Or to be like this much better:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['age'])){
$name = $_GET['name'];
$age = $_GET ['age'];

echo "Hello $name. Congratulations on being $age years old!";
}else{
?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
        <p>What's your name?</br><input type="text" name="name"></p>
        <p>How old are you?</br><input type="text" name="age"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Skicka"></p>
    </form>
<?php
}
?>
```

like this you can paste this code anywhere you like and it will work without modification...

Answer (score -2):

This is the correct form of your `get.php`:

```
<?php

$name = $_GET['name'];
$age = $_GET ['age'];

echo "Hello ".$name." Congratulations on being ".$age." years old!";

?>
```

Comment: The "correct" way to do it is whatever your preference is. I personally like "Hello {$name} Congratulations on being {$age} years old." It will work regardless in this case. Downvoted since this is an opinion and not an answer :p